# Exception with asynchronous request with Jersey application after updating from karaf 2.4.2 to 4.2.6

Tags: jersey, jetty, apache-karaf

After updating the karaf from 2.4.2 to 4.2.9 getting the following exception. I'm using jersey 2.25.1. Below is the stack trace,

I tried with different version of Jersey but the issue persists.

```
 javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Attempt to suspend a connection of an asynchronous request failed in the underlying container.
    javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Attempt to suspend a connection of an asynchronous request failed in the underlying container.
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489) ~[181:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.25.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427) ~[181:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.25.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388) ~[181:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.25.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341) ~[181:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.25.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228) ~[181:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.25.1]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873) ~[159:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623) ~[159:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at com.example.CustomFilter.doFilter(CustomFilter.java:84) ~[40:com.exampple.api:0.0.1]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602) ~[159:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:214) ~[169:org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) ~[159:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540) ~[159:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:71) ~[202:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:7.2.10]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146) ~[158:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) ~[156:org.eclipse.jetty.security:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[158:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257) ~[158:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700) ~[158:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255) ~[158:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345) ~[158:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:293) ~[202:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:7.2.10]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203) ~[158:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480) ~[159:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667) ~[158:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201) ~[158:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247) ~[158:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144) ~[158:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:80) ~[202:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:7.2.10]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[158:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505) ~[158:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370) ~[158:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267) ~[158:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305) ~[150:org.eclipse.jetty.io:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) ~[150:org.eclipse.jetty.io:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117) ~[150:org.eclipse.jetty.io:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333) ~[161:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310) ~[161:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168) ~[161:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:132) ~[161:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698) [161:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804) [161:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.4.18.v20190429]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:?]
    Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Attempt to suspend a connection of an asynchronous request failed in the underlying container.
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:328) ~[184:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.25.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102) ~[184:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.25.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326) ~[184:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.25.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) ~[183:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.25.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) ~[183:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.25.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) ~[183:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.25.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) ~[183:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.25.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) ~[183:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.25.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) ~[183:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.25.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305) ~[184:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.25.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154) ~[184:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.25.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473) ~[181:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.25.1]
        ... 53 more
```

Some other posts suggest to add  in web.xml, but I don't have any web.xml.

Comment: Need more information.  Do you have a stacktrace or anything that give more information on the cause?

Comment: Hi @JoakimErdfelt, added stack trace.

Comment: have you setup the async-supported configurations in your web.xml yet? - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420631/jersey-error-when-trying-to-suspend-a-connection-of-an-asynchronous-request

Comment: Your custom `com.example.CustomFilter` would need to be flagged as async-supported as well (also in your web.xml).